# Unable to boot after installing fglrx. Changing mirrors?

Tags: drivers, gnome, updates, ati, fglrx

To start, I am only a beginner with Linux
So i installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.04. Installs and runs fine. After I reboot from installing fglrx, I cannot boot into the GNOME desktop. So, I entered recovery mode to remove fglrx

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
```

only to be prompted that it wasn't installed. So I

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and I get a couple errors that some indexes failed to download. Moving on in the forums I found, I

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and get the error "Unable to fetch some archives"
I found something on changing mirrors, but the forums were not so friendly on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After booting into recovery mode you first have to enable the network.
There is a menu entry in the same overview where you select the root account.

Now execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge fglrx
```

Comment: I enabled network and got different results. after `purge fglrx` I was prompted that it wasn't installed. So I `install fglrx` and the install procedure looks fine, but I am still unable to boot to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

That could be `fglrx-updates`, not `fglrx`. Those are different packages. Try to `sudo apt-get purge fglrx-updates fglrx-updates-core`.